# dividing unit square onto infinitely many rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Is it possible to divide the unit square onto infinitely many rectangles of dimensions $\frac{1}{x_n}\times\frac{1}{y_n}$ where $(x_n),(y_n)$ are increasing sequences of integers?

Comment: Strictly increasing? And you want to find such sequences?

Comment: yes, increasing means strictly increasing; I ask if there exists at least one pair of such sequences

Comment: I strongly suspect not.  We would have to have $x_n=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots, y_n=2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$ because the total area for these is $1$ and any other pair of strictly increasing sequences will have an area less than $1$.  I don't know a proof that you will always get stuck trying to fit them.

Comment: This was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164035/regular-way-to-fill-a-1-times1-square-with-frac1n-times-frac1n1-re) and no successful answer was given.

Comment: It might be the case that the usual $\frac1k \times \frac1{k+1}$ packing problem has an affirmative answer, and yet this problem (in which all of them have to have the same orientation) does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316594901163) shows that all these rectangles can be packed into a square of side $133/132$ and states that the question of whether they can be packed into the unit square is open.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/can-we-cover-the-unit-square-by-these-rectangles